# Retrieving current user id inside a function defined into class (CreateView)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, model

Is possible to retrieve the current logged user id into a function defined inside a class, in views.py, using Django CreateView?

Something like this:

```py
class CreationClass(CreateView):
    model = Mymodel
    def creation(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid:
                 form = myForm()
                 user_id = self.request.user.id
                 rel_table = Item_id_user ( item_id = form.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                 rel_table.save() #<--- this does not save, even if table exists
        return render(request, ''mypage.html')
```

And this is my models.py

```py
class Item(models.Model):

     id_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_item', 
               verbose_name='id utente', through='Item_id_user')
     object = models.Manager()

     # table to handle relationship
class Item_id_user(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

What I want to achieve is to store into Item_id_user, but nothing at all is being stored. I thought the problem was the `request.user.id`.

Comment: Ok this was not my question. Anyway, if i print user_id in my terminal,i can't see the value... i was thinking there is an error in what i wrote...

Comment: Yes, I noticed and deleted my answer later. You can use it as in the example you gave. If self.request or self.request.user were not available,  an exception would be raised.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
user_id = self.request.user.id
```

try this:

```
user_id = request.user.id
```

Should work.

Comment: It's a little bit weird, i'll add the rest of my code because this isn't working

Comment: Try this in line 9: rel_table = Item_id_user ( item_id = form.id, user_id = request.user)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you re-initialize the form with form = MyForm() after the form is validated. I think that might wipe the data contained in it. It looks like you forgot it there.

Try this:

```
class CreationClass(CreateView):
model = Mymodel
def creation(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ColumnCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid:
             # form = myForm()
             user_id = self.request.user.id
             rel_table = Item_id_user ( item_id = form.id, user_id = request.user.id)
             rel_table.save() #<--- this does not save, even if table exists
    return render(request, ''mypage.html')
```

Comment: you are right, my bad... but this not solved my issue... in another function i do the same thing to store in another relationship table (i'm using m2m). No problem to store, in this function